# Посчитать количество элементов в объекте JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть простой объект:

```
var obj = {
    0: {
        a: 1,
        status: 0
    },
    1: {
        b: 1,
        status: 0
    },
    2: {
        c: 1,
        status: 1
    }
}
```

Как посчитать, сколько в объекте `status: 0`?

Comment: Если структуру знаете, то перебором с проверкой.

Comment: без перебора никак?

Comment: Подождите, может другие варианты будут в ответах.

Comment: не очень хочется нагружать циклами...(

Comment: @N0ob, если структура циклическая, то без циклов (явных или неявных) никак.

Comment: @N0ob, а чем вам так перебор не угодил?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно обойтись без перебора:

```
JSON.stringify(obj).match(/"status":0/g).length
```

Смысл такой:

- Приводим в JSON: `JSON.stringify(obj)` вернет `"{"0":{"a":1,"status":0},"1":{"b":1,"status":0},"2":{"c":1,"status":1}}"`
- Ищем совпадения ключей: `.match(/"status":0/g)` вернет `[""status":0", ""status":0"]`
- Смотрим количество совпадений: `.length` вернет `2`

Comment: `JSON.stringify` все равно использует рекуррентный обход объекта. Пусть и не явно для JS кода.

Comment: Согласен, но если задумываться, практически любой алгоритм состоит из последовательностей, ветвлений и циклов. Если копать глубже в js-движок, то не останется способов написать программу без использования циклов. Бёма-Якопини подтвердят)

Comment: Так а я же и не спорю =) Вопрос тут на самом деле всего один: будет ли `JSON.stringify` + `String.prototype.match` быстрее чем обычный цикл. Потому, что по памяти оно однозначно проигрывает.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev про производительность я бы тоже почитал с интересом. Поделитесь по теме, если знаете чем, буду благодарен)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/stringify-vs-for `JSON.stringify` существенно медленнее (у меня более чем вдвое)

Comment: @MiKeBu Спасибо давно искал такой способ)

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, без перебора, будет всё-же не обойтись.

```js
var obj = {
  0: {
    a: 1,
    status: 0
  },
  1: {
    b: 1,
    status: 0
  },
  2: {
    c: 1,
    status: 1
  }
}

var leng = 0;
for (var s in obj) {
  if (obj[s].status === 0) {
    leng++;
  }
}

console.log(leng); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.values(obj).filter(el=> el['status'] === 0).length
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, да нормальный ответ.

Comment: @AndrewZyuzin, я бы `['status']` заменил на `.status`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, опять напоминаю про «уловку 22»: тем, кому кусок кода понятен без пояснений, этот кусок кода и не нужен вовсе: они ж его и сами при необходимости могут написать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а те, кому непонятен, могут сходить на MDN, прочитать про 2 использованные функции и понять ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy, и, финализируя мысль: не нужен этот сайт, ведь есть mdn, где всё подробно изложено.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, но js не ограничивается 2 функциями. Ответ указывает, что конкретно надо использовать, а за подробной информацией можно и на mdn заглянуть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть такая ещё древнеримская поговорка «vox populi vox dei». посмотрим, [какие ответы тут предпочитают «плюсовать»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa) (т.е. считают их, например, полезными, или интересными). вот я вижу, что в большинстве это — весьма развёрнутые ответы. да, навреняка там где-нибудь в этой массе можно отыскать и краткие, состоящие, как и обсуждаемый, из «голого куска кода», который как бы «призван направить на путь истинный» — погуглить и почитать. но такие ответы явно не очень высоко ценятся посетителями данного сайта.

Answer (score -1):

`function count(obj) { return Object.keys(obj).length; }`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]